# Sorting users by reputation: "top X%" is off by a factor of 10

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, user-profile-page

Looking at (e.g.) [my own](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep) user page, I'm listed as "top 0.89% overall". As I'm no. 5 of >5000 users at the moment, this should be "top 0.089% overall".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK only users with more than 200rep are taken into account. The rest don't count yet as full site members. If you go to http://stackexchange.com/leagues/29/ you will see in the right side bar that only about 10% of the users have 200rep or more, which explains the factor of 10.

Comment: +1 for a possible explanation. I'd still regard the display as rather misleading -- "top 0.89%" of the "top 10%", so to speak.

Comment: ...top 90%, you mean.

Comment: As Jeff has retagged my question from "bug" to "support": Answer accepted.